# Gradle sync error after changing build platform

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I opened my project it first said I had no build platform tools for version 26 which I changed to 25.0.3 now I am getting this issue:

> Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments
>   [build_83ss0a431bhzra8y3dug13x1y$_run_closure3@6184756f] on root
>   project 'AssetTrack' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

How to solve this issue can anybody help ?

This is my build.gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
}
```

even all of dependencies are gone

Comment: share your build.gradle

Comment: share your project structure screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Close Android Studio and manually navigate to your project's **root directory** from windows explorer. Open the file **build.gradle** with notepad and cut the android closure:

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 21
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }
```

Back to the project's root directory goto the **/app** folder. Open the **build.gradle** file with notepad and paste the android block there so that it becomes:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Finally, Open the Android Studio and sync the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Move these into your app.gradle file

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
de

Comment: I can't I don't have that file and it is showing that error again and again every time I sync

Comment: There are 2 Gradle Files Right 1 at the project level and 1 at app level , Dont you have the app Level Gradle File .if so create it.

Comment: Do I need to download platform tools 26

Comment: These Information Regrading the Gradle realted to android Should be inside the App gradle file, Platform downloading wont help